# Reverting a CTE (Common Table Expressin)

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

I've asked a question before but I obscured the query so much that I wasn't able to take the solution and apply it to my original query. Therefore, I'm trying this again.

I have a CTE that I need to revert into a "normal" query for MySQL 5.6. We aren't upgrading to MySQL 8 or MariaDB 10.x anytime soon for this project.

The query is as follows:

```
        WITH currentUserPermissions (permissionID, action, level) AS (
            SELECT
                p.permissionID,
                p.action,
                CASE WHEN p.level = 1 AND rp.level = 1 THEN 2 ELSE COALESCE(rp.level, 0) END AS level
            FROM user_org_sport op
                JOIN rolePermissions rp ON op.roleID = rp.roleID AND op.orgID = rp.orgID
                JOIN permissions p ON p.permissionID = rp.permissionID
            WHERE op.userProfileID = :userID
                AND op.orgID = :orgID
                AND p.systemFlag = 0
        )

        SELECT action, level
        FROM currentUserPermissions

        UNION

        SELECT p.action, p.level
        FROM permissions p
        WHERE p.systemFlag = -1

        UNION

        SELECT p.action, 0 AS level
        FROM permissions p
            LEFT JOIN currentUserPermissions cup ON cup.action = p.action
        WHERE cup.action IS NULL
            AND p.systemFlag = 0
```

I'm not a database sme (subject mater expert) so any help would be appreciated. It is my lack of database experience why I wasn't able to apply the previous answer to my query.

Comment: it is almost just as simple as copy/pasting all the SQL including the parenthesis form the CTE on the places in the query where `currentUserPermissions` is used and make delived tables  (subqueries) from them.. Keep in mind you might have to include aliases..

Comment: So `FROM currentUserPermissions` becomes -> `FROM (SELECT
                p.permissionID,
                p.action, ...) AS alias` and `LEFT JOIN currentUserPermissions cup ` becomes -> `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT
                p.permissionID,
                p.action, ...  ) AS  cup `

Comment: I’m stepping away for some food and will try this when I get back. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to copy the CTE once for every reference you have to it:

```
SELECT action, level
FROM (
    SELECT
        p.permissionID,
        p.action,
        CASE WHEN p.level = 1 AND rp.level = 1 THEN 2 ELSE COALESCE(rp.level, 0) END AS level
    FROM user_org_sport op
    JOIN rolePermissions rp ON op.roleID = rp.roleID AND op.orgID = rp.orgID
    JOIN permissions p ON p.permissionID = rp.permissionID
    WHERE op.userProfileID = :userID
      AND op.orgID = :orgID
      AND p.systemFlag = 0
) x

UNION

SELECT p.action, p.level
FROM permissions p
WHERE p.systemFlag = -1

UNION

SELECT p.action, 0 AS level
FROM permissions p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        p.permissionID,
        p.action,
        CASE WHEN p.level = 1 AND rp.level = 1 THEN 2 ELSE COALESCE(rp.level, 0) END AS level
    FROM user_org_sport op
    JOIN rolePermissions rp ON op.roleID = rp.roleID AND op.orgID = rp.orgID
    JOIN permissions p ON p.permissionID = rp.permissionID
    WHERE op.userProfileID = :userID
      AND op.orgID = :orgID
      AND p.systemFlag = 0
) cup ON cup.action = p.action
WHERE cup.action IS NULL
  AND p.systemFlag = 0
```

Of course the MySQL 5.x way adds redundancy to your query, and also it becomes slower since the CTE may need to be computed twice instead of a single time.